# The screen shot is taken before buttons are removed from the window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, system.io.file

**The task:** 
On the window there are several buttons showing. There is a moment when they should be removed from the screen. After those buttons are completely removed/hidden, only then the screen shot should be taken.

**The problem:**
Screen shot is taken before the buttons are removed from the screen.

**Additional info:**
As there is a long running operation in background, and I need to keep the UI responsive, I'm using asyncronous tasks. `Dispatcher.Invoke` is used to be able to work with controls in multithreaded environment. `RemoveTemplateButtons()` basically just removes all the buttons from the screen. `CaptureScreenAndSave()` creates a screenshot and save it to the folder. Also one thing to menthion, when debugging, the buttons are removed when the breakpoint exits the `else` statement.

**The code:**

```
//show the loading screen
loadingWindow.Show();

var slowTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        if ( /* ... */)
        {

        }
        /* THE SCREENSHOT SHOULD BE TAKEN AFTER BUTTONS ARE REMOVED FROM SCREEN */
        else
        {
            //remove template buttons from screen
            this.RemoveTemplateButtons();

            //captures screenshot of window and saves into folder
            this.CaptureScreenAndSave();
        }
    }));
});

//long running operation
await slowTask.ContinueWith((s) =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, count - 1, i =>
    {
        //do some work
    });
});
//waits till long running operations are done
await slowTask;

//some other logic ( syncronous )

//hide loading screen
loadingWindow.Close();
```

**EDIT**- Remove template buttons method

```
private void RemoveTemplateButtons()
{
     //in case if image searching happens more than once
     foreach (var btn in templButtonDictionary)
     {
         canvasBackground.Children.Remove(btn.Value);
     }
     templButtonDictionary.Clear();
}
```

Comment: can you include some of the logic from `RemoveTemplateButtons()`? Is any of the code in the explicitly asynchronous?

Comment: `btn.Value` looks very suspicious here. I am nearly certain that `Remove` expects a reference to a `Button` and not its value, which is never directly a child of the canvas.

Comment: If the value is `Button` then it could cause some weird behaviour? @codesparkle

Comment: I found the solution.. That method `CaptureScreenAndSave` needs to be placed inside `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and set priority to `ApplicationIdle`. More info - [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506016/how-to-know-when-window-control-styling-completed/31506946?noredirect=1#comment50977053_31506946)